# Average of a function and center of mass

Tags: physics, average, centroid

The geometric center of an object is the center of mass of an object with uniform density.
The average height of a semicircular wire is $\pi R/4$ where R is the radius. But the actual y coordinate of the center of mass is $2R/\pi$ why is it different? someone help.
I calculated the average height by using the standard formula, $$\frac{1}{2r}\int_{-r}^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \,dx= \frac{\pi R}{4}$$. and the second result was by using the standard substitu[image]

Comment: If you include how you calculated these two results it would make it possible for a user here to see that you set the two results up correctly, and would also help explain things if in fact the two calculations are really of two different quantities that one should not expect to give the same results.

Comment: You're averaging the $y$ values over the range of the $x$ values which is a range of $2r$. To get the center of mass, we average over the points on the semicircle which have a range of $\pi r$.

Comment: In other words, your mass element is different for different $x$, even if the projected length along the $x$ axis is the same

Comment: what? do you mean exactly? Isn't the average height of a function basically a weighted average with respect to position, which is basically the center of mass?

Comment: No. The center of mass represents the average mass. The total mass is the density of the material times the length of the semicircle. The length of the semicircle is $\pi R$, not $2R$. Also, is it really difficult to write complete sentences? "what? do you mean exactly?" sounds like a bad Captain Kirk impersonation.

Comment: what does the average of a function represent, then, average height basically y-coordinate of the center of mass. help

Comment: You say you have a weighted average, but your weight is wrong. If you think of the integral as a sum, with $\Delta x$ as the width along the $x$ axis of each piece, then you sum together the $y$ coordinates. But you give them the same weight $\Delta x$. That's not right for the center of mass. A piece at the beginning or end of the semicircle is almost perpendicular to the $x$ axis, while at the middle is almost parallel. So even though the projections along $x$ are $\Delta x$, the length along $y$ axis are going to be different, so the masses are going to be different